# python list confusion

Tags: python, list, coding-style

hi i have a situation like this:

```
>>> def get():
...     for i in range(3):
...             yield [0]
...
```

and i want to get this: [0,0,0]

my code now works in this way:

```
>>> r = []
>>> r.extend(i[0] for i in get())
>>> r
[0, 0, 0]
```

but i don't like i[0]..
some advice?

(i'm on python3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> r.extend(i[0] for i in get())

This kind of imperative code (stateful, with inplace updates) is asking for trouble. That seems the canonical use for a functional [flatten](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#recipes) ([concat](http://zvon.org/other/haskell/Outputprelude/concat_f.html)):

```
from itertools import chain

def flatten(listOfLists):
    return chain.from_iterable(listOfLists)

def get():
    for i in range(3):
        yield [0]

print(list(flatten(get())))
# [0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks very strange, but I assume it's very simplified. If it's just about getting rid of the `i[0]`, do this:

```
>>> def get():
...     for i in range(3):
...             yield 0
... 
>>> r = []
>>> r.extend(get())
>>> r
[0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: Why the `[i for i in get()]`? This needlessly allocates a list, and `i for i in ` is a tautology.

Answer (score 1):

To me, this looks like `get` can only ever return a list of length 1. If that's the case, drop the braces:

```
>>> def get():
...     for i in range(3):
...             yield 0
>>> # Or, shorter ...
>>> get = lambda: (0 for i in range(3))
>>> r = []
>>> r.extend(get())
>>> r
[0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: or even shorter: `get = lambda: [0]*3`.

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y Nope that's shorter in code, but creates a list  instead of a generator. For large values of 3, your solution allocates lots of potentially unneeded memory.

Comment: @philhag I like the idea of "large values of 3" = that could make maths interesting :-)

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are having to use `i[0]` is because `get()` is a generator that returns a `list` of size 1 every time it is called. So your code `i[0] for i in get()` is the same as `i[0] for i in  ([0],[0],[0])`. The reason your code works is that `i[0]` gets the first element off the returned element which is itself the `list [0]`.

What I gather from your question is that you want to have `i for i in [0,0,0]`. As mentioned in other answers this can be achieved by changing you generator to yield the `int` `0` instead of the `list` `[0]`. You can see the result of the generator in the following example code:

```
>>> for i in get():
...   print("i={} and i[0]={}".format(i, i[0]))
... 
i=[0] and i[0]=0
i=[0] and i[0]=0
i=[0] and i[0]=0
```

As you can see, your generator returns a `[0]` every iteration and that is the reason you have to use `i[0]` to get the first element of each list.

Also, since `r` is just the results of the generator, you can simplify by just doing the following:

```
>>> def gen():
...   for i in range(3):
...     yield 0
... 
>>> r = list(gen())
>>> r
[0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't yield an array if you don't want one:

```
>>> def get():
...  for i in range(3):
...   yield 0
... 
>>> r = []
>>> r.extend(i for i in get())
>>> r
[0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this instead:

```
def get():
    return [0] * 3

r = [] 
r.extend(get())
r
[0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

???

```
def get():
    for i in xrange(3):
        yield 0

r = list(get())

print r
```

or

```
gen = (0 for i in xrange(3))

r = list(gen)

print r
```

Comment: i already have a function that yield [someint] and i can't modify it